# Terraform - create list based on resource count query returned no results

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create dynamically create a list of instance ids, to assign it to the load balancer. Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280855/terraform-create-list-based-on-resource-count) I found I can do it using `data "aws_instances"`. Unfortunately I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.
```

This is the way I create my EC2 resources

```
resource "aws_instance" "one" {
  instance_type = "${var.lc_instance_type}"
  ami           = "${var.dev_ami}"
  count         = "${var.instance_count}"
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.name_prefix}-id"
  }
}
```

And this is the way I'm using the data aws_instance and how I planned to use it in the EB resource

```
data "aws_instances" "read-ec2" {
  instance_tags= {
    Name = "${var.name_prefix}-id"
  }
}

resource "aws_elb" "loadbalancer" {
  instances = ["${data.aws_instances.read-ec2.ids}"]

  listener {
    ...
  }
}
```

Not sure if I'm using the `instance_tags` option properly.

Comment: It might be helpful to show the actual tags of the instances to confirm they are indeed `${var.name_prefix}-id}`. Also, the first resource has a syntax error in the tags (guessing unrelated).

Comment: @Diego - not so important, but you are missing the link to the other question.

Comment: Added the link, not sure what happen